# Calling pointer to member function from another class

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a quadrature class for which I would like to be able to pass any integrand into, regardless of whether the function defining the integrand is a free function or a member function of another class.  For the latter case, the best progress I've made is like the following.

Class `ChiSquared` contains a pointer to the `GaussQuadrature` class and passes a member function to the `GaussQuadrature` named `Quad` like so:

```
double ChiSquared::LowerIncompleteGammaIntegrand(double x) {
  return pow(x, (5/2.0)-1)*exp(-x);
}    

double ChiSquared::LowerIncompleteGamma(double x) {                               
  Quad->Quadrature(&ChiSquared::LowerIncompleteGammaIntegrand, other args...);
  return Quad->getQuad();
}
```

In the `GaussQuadrature` template class, the `Quadrature` function that accepts this call is

```
template<typename T>
void GaussQuadrature<T>::
Quadrature(double (ChiSquared::*Integrand)(double), other args...)
{
   T val = Integrand(argument);
   ...
   // other math stuff
}
```

Firstly, This generates the error

```
error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘Integrand (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* Integrand) (...)’
```

which makes it seem like I need an instance of `ChiSquared` in the `GaussQuadrature` class, not the other way around, and I want to avoid this because:

Secondly, I want to decouple the `GaussQuadature` class from any other classes, as mentioned before.  Ideally, ANY function would be able to be passed in as an "integrand" and so I don't want to have to declare a separate `Quadrature` function for each possible type of class the "integrand" could come from.  Could I use some sort of function template here?

Comment: If you make `ChiSquared::LowerIncompleteGammaIntegrand` static it will be free (not have a this).

Comment: alternativly look up `lambda`s, then you can wrap it in an anonymous function, that can bind `this`.

Comment: Or make one of your `other args...` the pointer to the `ChiSquared` object on which to do the firing. To do your second requirement would need an overload using a *non* member function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
double ChiSquared::LowerIncompleteGamma(double x) {
    std::function<double(double)> f =
        std::bind( &ChiSquared::LowerIncompleteGammaIntegrand, *this, _1 );
    Quad->Quadrature(f, other args...);
    return Quad->getQuad();
}
```

where `GaussQuadrature` is modified to take a `function<...>` argument, or made into a template:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename F>
void GaussQuadrature<T>::
Quadrature(const F& Integrand, other args...)
{
   T val = Integrand(argument);
   ...
   // other math stuff
}
```

Here, [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) binds the `ChiSquared` object `*this` with its method `LowerIncompleteGammaIntegrand()`, giving a function that takes a `double` argument and returns a `double`; then, [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) represents this only with its signature `double(double)`, hiding the underlying type `ChiSquared`.

By the way, some things are apparently missing, e.g. I can't see where parameter `x` is used in `ChiSquared::LowerIncompleteGamma()`, or where `argument` comes from in `GaussQuadrature<T>::Quadrature()`.

Comment: +1 this is a straight-forward solution to *both* issues raised, while still allowing `ChiSquared` the ability to fire-my-member.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should omit the other class from the function signature?

```
template<typename T> void GaussQuadrature<T>::
Quadrature(double (*Integrand)(double), other args...)
{
   T val = Integrand(argument);
   ...
   // other math stuff
}
```